# Wordpress update to 4.7 causes Magento/Fishpig integration to redirect base URL to the Wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I've copied a live site to a test server to test updating Wordpress on a Magento site that uses Fishpig to bridge content from Wordpress to Magento.  Since the udpate, the site always redirects from the homepage to the wordpress folder.  e.g. dev.site.com goes to dev.site.com/wordpress.  It's not an .htaccess issues, if I wipe them out in both directories it still does it, if I rename index.php in the wordpress folder it stops it but breaks the preview.  If I rename the theme and plugins folders it still redirects, something in the core is causing it but I am having issues figuring out what it is.  Thanks.

Also if I change the site to show the latest blog post instead of the static home page, it doesn't redirect but shows the blog page.

Answer (score 1):

We will need more information to help solve your problem.

1. Are your FishPig extensions at the latest version?
2. What FishPig add-on extensions, if any, are you using?
3. Have you tried disabling all WordPress plugins?
4. Do you have any error messages in System > Configuration > WordPress?

My guess is that your WordPress URLs aren't setup correctly and you're using an out dated add-on extension (eg. Visual Composer). There was a bug in older versions of some add-ons that caused this issue, but this has now been fixed.

If you can provide the actual link to your dev site, it will make debugging the issue much easier.